# Zend Framework 2.2.1 on XAMPP

Tags: xampp, zend-framework2

I am trying to install ZendFramework latest version on XAMPP. I added  XAMPP directory on environment variables.XAMPP server works properly on 8080 port. After that I installed git and  ran below commands respectively:

```
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git zendtest
cd zendtest
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```

and I didn't get any error. After that I added these lines to C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\http-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

    <DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/zendtest/public"
    ServerName www.zendtest.loc zendtest.loc
    ServerAlias zendtest.loc
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/zendtest/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
  <DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs">
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

And added this line to hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1:8080 zendtest.loc localhost
```

With these adjusments apache server on XAMPP doesn't work. When I press the start button for apache server, XAMPP application doesn't respond. Whenever I restore http-vhosts.conf file, XAMPP works properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your Appache start at all? I'm no expert, but as far as i know, `ServerName www.zendtest.loc` is all that's allowed for one line. Your `ServerAlias zendtest.loc` is the alias

Comment: Apache doesn't start. But if I restore httpd-vhosts.conf file, it starts. I guess ServerAlias is not the point. It is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
I am able to notice a typo error in the httpd-vhosts.conf file. Please replace this line <DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/zendtest/public" with  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/zendtest/public" (remove the preceding angular bracket).

I checked this in my local box Xampp was refusing to start but works fine after removing the angular bracket.
```